# Reissue US, UK, Canada visas in stolen passports

Tags: usa, uk, passports, canada, lost-documents

My bag was stolen with my 3 Pakistani passports having US, UK & Canada visas. Can anyone guide me how to get the visas back, on my new passports?

Comment: How is it that you have 3 passports all issued by Pakistan?

Answer (score 15):

This answer assumes you are not in any of the three countries mentioned.

US: To replace a visa from outside the USA, you must apply in person at a U.S. Embassy or Consulate abroad. When applying for the replacement of a visa, you will need to provide a written account documenting the loss of your passport and visa. Include a copy of the police report. https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/lost-stolen-visas.html

UK: You need to apply for a replacement using transfer of conditions. A police report or other evidence that satisfactorily establishes that the passport is no longer in your  possession is required. https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa

Canada: it looks as if you can’t replace a lost or stolen visa from outside Canada. You will need to apply for a new visa. http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=044&top=12

Comment: @FreeMan, OP clearly mentioned their new passport. I don't think we need to mention getting a new passport before applying for new visas.

Comment: @Catsunami wow, total reading fail. My bad.