# Lost Passport with US Visa

Tags: visas, usa, passports, lost-documents

I am currently living in Geneva. I lost my Indian passport with US visa and I am wondering if I should apply for the Visa from Bern or from India. I contacted the Indian consulate and they told me they will get me a new passport in a couple of weeks. Has any body been in this situation before? How did it go?

Comment: Possible duplicate or related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142547/reissue-us-uk-canada-visas-in-stolen-passports/142550#142550